# Reconstruction of stereo image from single view images

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

How can I reconstruct an image from the stereo image pairs using OpenCV?

Comment: Maybe better on dsp.stackexchange.com?

Comment: What do you want as the output: a 2D image, a mesh, a depthmap?

Answer (score 0):

This is not necessarily an easy-to-solve problem. The thing is that both images store almost the same information, but from a slightly different perspective (angle and distance). So you have a perspective for each 2 of the stereo-optics. The only way to restore this is if(a) you knew what this perspective would be, e.g. a relative position-vector between both perspectives and the angle for both, you could create a mapping for a pixel in one of the images to the other.

The color of this (mapped) pixel ought to be the same, but as older stereo-optic-systems mapped to blue and red, you might have different values and thus have gained information doing this. Still, without these perspectives, you will need to correlate both pictures to each other and do quite complex image processing. I would suggest using scholar.google.com, unfortunately I failed to find anything useful, if you also can't find it there, start a phd ;)

Anyone who does know an algorithm of method to somehow restore such images, please let me know :) I am very curious about this as well.